# Google Script Mapping

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping

I was trying to use mapping on Google Script to enter a value on the City (id="city") field and show the Price (id="price") with the script below. The code below doesn't work and didn't provide any result on the price textbox. Moreover, would it be possible to do a multiple conditions? I mean the price will be displayed base on the City, Products, and Quantity. I have provided the image below. Thanks!

```
  <script>
 
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",getPrice);

    function getPrice(){
      vCity = document.getElementById("city").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHander(updatePrice).getAmount(vCity);

    }

    function updatePrice(myprice) {
      document.getElementById("price").value = myprice;
    }

  </script>
```

Here's my gs.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}


function getAmount(city) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FhWlaXixXPxq8EnHICfVR207aIkxtkzOgvdvt3hHuuI/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Pricing");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

  var cityList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var priceList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  var position = cityList.indexOf(city);

  if(position > -1){
    return priceList[position];
  } else {
    return "Unavailable";
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. I ran it as a dialog.  I changed the sheetname.

```
function launchmypricedialog() {
  let html = '<input type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" /><br /><input type="text" id="price" /><br /><input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn"/><script>document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",getPrice);function getPrice(){let vCity = document.getElementById("city").value;google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatePrice).getAmount(vCity);}function updatePrice(myprice) {console.log(myprice);document.getElementById("price").value = myprice;}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'test');
}

function getAmount(city) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  var cityList = data.map(function (r) { return r[0]; });
  var priceList = data.map(function (r) { return r[1]; });
  //console.log(city);
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(cityList));
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(priceList));
  var position = cityList.indexOf(city);
  //console.log(priceList[position]);
  if (position > -1) {
    return priceList[position];
  } else {
    return "Unavailable";
  }
}
```

This was my data

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| City1 | 12 |
| City2 | 2 |
| City3 | 24 |
| City4 | 18 |
| City5 | 14 |
| City6 | 3 |
| City7 | 17 |
| City8 | 5 |
| City9 | 29 |
| City10 | 24 |
| City11 | 8 |
| City12 | 26 |
| City13 | 15 |
| City14 | 25 |
| City15 | 0 |
| City16 | 25 |
| City17 | 17 |
| City18 | 11 |
| City19 | 22 |
| City20 | 10 |
| City21 | 16 |
| City22 | 0 |
| City23 | 6 |
| City24 | 22 |
| City25 | 15 |
| City26 | 11 |
| City27 | 13 |
| City28 | 14 |
| City29 | 22 |
| City30 | 24 |

My Dialog:

[image]